# Problems regarding Pyomo provided math functions

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, optimization, pyomo

I am trying to solve a maximization problem using Pyomo which has a recursive relationship. I am trying to maximize the revenue from a battery and it involves updating the state of charge of the battery every hour (which is the recursive relationship here). I am using the following code:

```
import pyomo
import numpy as np
from pyomo.environ import *    
import pandas as pd

model = ConcreteModel()

N = 24 #number of hours
lmpdata = np.random.randint(1,10,24) #LMP Data (to be imported from MISO/PJM)
R = 0 #discount
eta_s = 0.99 #self-discharge efficiency
eta_c = 0.95 #round-trip efficiency
gammas_min = 0.1 #fraction of energy capacity to reserve for discharging
gammas_max = 0.05 #fraction of energy capacity to reserve for charging
S_bar = 50 #energy capacity
Q_bar = 50 #energy charge/discharge rating

model.qd = Var(range(N), within = NonNegativeReals) #variables for energy sold at time t
model.qr = Var(range(N), within = NonNegativeReals) #variables for energy purchased at time t

model.obj = Objective(expr = sum((model.qd[i]-model.qr[i])*lmpdata[i]*np.exp(-R*(i+1)) for i in range(N)), sense = maximize) #objective function

model.SOC = np.zeros(N) #state of charge (s(t) in Sandia's Model)
model.SOC[0] = 25 #SOC at hour 0

#recursion relation describing the SOC
def con_rule1(model,i):
    model.SOC[i] = eta_s*model.SOC[i-1] + eta_c*model.qr[i-1] - model.qd[i-1]
    return  (eta_s*model.SOC[i-1] + eta_c*model.qr[i-1] - model.qd[i-1]== model.SOC[i])

#def con_rule1(model,i):
model.con1 = Constraint(range(1,N), rule = con_rule1)
#model.con2 = Constraint(expr = eta_s*SOC[N-1] + eta_c*model.qr[N-1] - model.qd[N-1] == SOC[0]) #SOC relation for the last hour

#SOC boundaries
def con_rule2(model,i):
    return (gammas_min*S_bar <= eta_s*model.SOC[i] + eta_c*model.qr[i] - model.qd[i] <= (1-gammas_max)*S_bar)

model.con3 = Constraint(range(N), rule = con_rule2)


#limits the total energy charged over each time step to the energy
#charge limit (derived from the power limit)
#It restricts the throughput based on the power rating
def con_rule3(model,i):
    return (0 <= model.qr[i]+model.qd[i] <= Q_bar)

model.con4 = Constraint(range(N),rule = con_rule3)

def pyomo_postprocess(options=None, instance=None, results=None):
  model.qd.display()
  model.qr.display()


model.pprint()
```

However, when I try to run the code, I am getting the following error:

```
Implicit conversion of Pyomo NumericValue type `<class 'pyomo.core.kernel.expr_coopr3._SumExpression'>' to a float is
disabled. This error is often the result of using Pyomo components as
arguments to one of the Python built-in math module functions when
defining expressions. Avoid this error by using Pyomo-provided math
functions.
```

I could not find any reference to Pyomo's math function in its documentation. It would be great if anyone could help me solve this problem!

Answer (score 1):

Pyomo defines its own set of math module functions for operations like `exp`, `log`, `sin`, etc. If you want to use any of these functions in your Pyomo expressions you should make sure they are the ones provided by Pyomo and not from some other Python package. I think the issue with your model is that you are using `np.exp` in your Objective function. The Pyomo math functions are automatically imported when you import `pyomo.environ` so you should be able to replace `np.exp` with `exp` to get the Pyomo-defined function.

Comment: Hi Bethany, thanks for your valuable input. However, I don't think the problem lies with the use of `np.exp` in the objective function as the model works fine even with it as long as I omit the line involving the the equation of the SOC in the function `con_rule1`. The main problem lies with the function `con_rule1`.

Comment: There are some known issues when using numpy objects in Pyomo expressions. (see: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/31). Your best bet is to replace `model.SOC` with a Pyomo Param.